# Changing the allowed fields based on user in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am building an inventory system where there is users with different levels of authority changing fields. I am trying to change the "protected $allowedFields" class property within a function inside the model, but it will not allow me. Do I have to create 2 different models, or bake the authentication into the html code? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
   

    class InventoryModel extends Model
       {
        protected $table = "tcg_main_inv";
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    
        protected $allowedFields = ['size'];
    
        public function setInvFields(string $userLevel)
        {
            if ($userLevel == "admin") {
                $allowedFields = ['container_number', 'size', 'dealer_cost', 'date_in', 
        'sales_order_number'];
            } else if ($userLevel)
                $allowedFields = ['date_in', 'sales_order_number'];
        }
```

Note: this is just a snippet of my model code.

Comment: Never tried to do so, but at glance you should setting it with `$this->allowedFields = [blablabla]`. Those are class properties, not simple variables in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @ViLar, I was able to figure out a solution that seems to work. I made a function inside the model that changes the allowed fields.

```
class InventoryModel extends Model
{
  protected $table = "tcg_main_inv";
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';


  protected $allowedFields;

  public function userAuth(string $user_type)
  {
    if($user_type == "dealer"){
        $this->allowedFields = [ 'container_number'];
    }
    else if ($user_type == "admin"){
        $this->allowedFields = ['size', 'container_number', 'dealer_cost'];
    }
     
  }
}
```